# SVG parser for C++? (Free or paid)

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

Does anybody know of a good SVG parser that puts out an SVG object in C++? I don't mind if it's free or paid. I'm just looking for one that is cleanly architected and adheres very well to the spec. Preferably one that would let me start rendering by just inspecting the structures and passing the info on to Cairo or QT.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in the SVG++ library, which is a lightweight C++ library to parse simple SVGs: https://github.com/svgpp/svgpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at the [Fog-Framework](http://code.google.com/p/fog/)